# How i can remove a newline from a list?

Tags: python, string, list

i have a list in python and i need to make it a string without newlines. i have this `['1\n2\n2\n,\n6\n2\n9\n,\n7\n1\n3']` and i want it to be `122,629,713` in a string instead of list. this is my code for the list:

```
follower = [driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div')[0].text]
follow = ''
for item in follower:
  item = item.strip('\n')
  item = item.strip('[')
  item = item.strip(']')
  item = item.strip("'")
  follow = follow + item
```

Comment: `item = item.replace('\n', '')`

Comment: ...because `strip()` only removed leading and trailing characters.

Comment: Thanks for help its working now

Comment: Please refrain from asking questions here that could easily be answered by reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str). Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation. Also note that what you want to do is remove them from strings *in a list*, not the list itself.

Comment: i searched a lot and didnt found anything. 2 hours i tried to find so i wrote it here. sorry for wasting you time.

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in follower:
    follow += item
print(follow.replace("\n",""))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to replace multiple characters the easiest way is to use a regular expression. You can separate the characters with `|` in a string and remember to escape special characters.

```
import re

chars_to_remove = "\n|'|\[|\]"
text = "1\n2\n2\n,]\n6\n2\n9\n,[\n7\n1\n3'"
re.sub(chars_to_remove, "", text)
```

Output:

```
'122,629,713'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm uncertain if you have a list of strings:

```
list_of_strings = ['1\n2\n2\n,\n6\n2\n9\n,\n7\n1\n3']
```

or just a string:

```
string = '1\n2\n2\n,\n6\n2\n9\n,\n7\n1\n3'
```

If you have a list of strings, just se a for loop to get every string, and then use the code below to do what you ask, other just iterate through the string

```
# CASE 1: you have a list of strings

for string in list_of_strings:
    fixed_string = ""
    for char in string:
        if char != '\n'
            fixed_string += char
    print(fixed string)


# CASE 2: you just have the string
fixed_string = ""
for char in string:
    if char != '\n'
        fixed_string += char
print(fixed_string)
```

Both cases should iterate through the string of characters and add them to the new string if they are not newline characters (\n).

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
>>> l=['1\n2\n2\n,\n6\n2\n9\n,\n7\n1\n3']
```

List comprehension and `.replace` on each string:

```
>>> [e.replace('\n','') for e in l]
['122,629,713']
```

Answer (score 0):

What i understood is you have a list `a=['1\n2\n2\n,\n6\n2\n9\n,\n7\n1\n3']` and you want to remove `\n` from it, and your desired outcome is `[122,629,713]`.
However a mistake is there in `list a`, as python will treat the item in the list as one item, `a should be a=['1\n2\n2\n','\n6\n2\n9\n','\n7\n1\n3']`

```
a=['1\n2\n2\n','\n6\n2\n9\n','\n7\n1\n3']
b=""
index=0
for i in a:
    c=i.replace("\n","")
    b+=f"{c},"
    if index==(len(a)-1):
        b=b[0:len(b)-1]
    index+=1
print(b)
#The outcome will be `122,629,713`
```

And if you want outcome as `[122,629,713]` then add after `for-loop`,

```
b=b.split(",")
# Now the outcome will be `[122,629,713]`
```